# Angular2, "replace" scrollbar

Tags: javascript, angular, scrollbar

I have an angular app with a scrollable sidenav.

This sidenav has the native ugly scrollbar. I want to replace this one with a styleable scrollbar.

Are there any good solutions for angular 2 which don't require jQuery?

Do I have to use an external JavaScript solution which doesn't rely on angular?

Thanks in advance!

PS: If important, I use Angular Material 2

PPS: I've already tried [gemini-scrollbar](https://github.com/noeldelgado/gemini-scrollbar), but this has broken the width of the sidenav and [simplebar](https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar) which has caused a ram overflow.

Edit:
I want to replase this ugly scrollbar:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the OVERVIEW EXAMPLE its better than Example tap section

this one:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, looks like  I didn't describe it clear enough. The sidenav is set to "side"-mode and is opened. I will add a picture of what I want to change

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JQuery to archive this task. It's pretty simple and easy to use ADD to do this. There's a example in this link https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/